# Is it advisable to install and keep programmes in sandboxes?

Tags: windows, sandbox, sandboxie

I have recently known about Sandboxie. This gave me an idea that I could install each programmes into an individual sandbox. I will then run the programmes from their sandboxes. I thought, this way, when I remove the programmes, they are dont leave any registry or file residues that could slow down my computer. But I'm not sure if this is going to cause more problems than being helpful.

Is it a good idea and advisable to do so? Is Sandboxie just for running suspicious programmes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sandboxie is designed for "suspicious" programs and not for daily use. A lot of programs will not function properly while sandboxed because they don't have the access to files they need to read/write to function.

Sandboxing a program means preventing it from using the registry or writing files - which a majority of programs need to do.

Comment: Also Sandboxie tends to copy stuff that the program needs inside the sandbo. Hence you will start having multiple copies of the same system binaries. Many applications (especially bulky ones)  just don't run well inside Sandboxie

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just curious, are there programmes that allow me to achieve something close to what I'd described?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, virtual machines. Otherwise, the nature of Windows is some "leftovers" from programs.